# ISBLANK returns False for empty cells having Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2016

In Excel 2016, a cell with formula which is not yet calculated appears blank. But still ISBLANK returns False.

I am trying to find a way to return True for the cell having formula which is not yet calculated and is actually Blank.

Can someone help me please.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: A blank cell contains nothing -- not even a formula with a result of nothing. Try `A1=""`

Comment: Nope. Not possible. Lets say, I have a cell C1 and it has formula: A1+B1. When I have not entered any values in A1 & B1, C1 will be empty. But still C1 returns False for ISBLANK. How can I check if C1 is actually Blank?

Comment: In your example C1 = 0 so is not blank or empty.

Comment: To echo the previous comment, in your example `C1` actually is calculated and equals 0. So this is not an example of "a cell with a formula which is not yet calculated." What is the actual formula you are using?

Comment: I am using =(ISBLANK(C1). It is returning False inspite of the cell is Blank. It doesnot make sense when the C1 does not contain any value (except formula). How can I check if cell only contains formula and not value?

Answer (score 25):

In case anyone else is having trouble with this, I found a solution.

If a formula returns an empty string, you can't use `ISBLANK()` because the presence of the formula makes the cell not functionally blank, even if it is visually blank.

But, you can use `IF()` and `LEN()` to test how many characters are in the cell. `LEN()` is a function that counts the number of characters present in a cell. A visually blank cell will have no characters to count.

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=0, "This cell is blank", "This cell contains characters")
```

Comment: This was exactly the simple solution for this. I am not sure why this wasn't accepted.

Comment: because it is doesn't work with range

Answer (score 6):

As per previous comments, ISBLANK will return FALSE even if your formula in cell C1 returns an empty string (""). ISBLANK will return TRUE only when a given cell is "truly" blank, i.e. does not contain any formulas or values.

As an alternative, try the following functions:

**=C1=""** <- will return TRUE, assuming that formula in C1 returns an empty string ("")

**=OR(ISBLANK(C1),C1="")** <- both formulas combined; will also work in case you remove your original formula from cell C1

**=NOT(ISNUMBER(C1))** <- will return TRUE in case the result of your numeric formula is empty (e.g. =IF(LEN(A1),A1+B1,""))

One more formula that you may find useful:

**=ISFORMULA(C1)**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

There are cases where a cell can possible contains one or more whitespaces, causing `LEN()` to fail. Use `trim()` combined with `len()` to overcome this issue, IF whitespace can be considered as a blank cell to you:

```
=IF(LEN(TRIM(A2))=0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=IF(A1="",""[VALUE IF TRUE],[VALUE OR A FUNCTION WHEN CONDITION IS FALSE])
```

instead of `isblank` because sometimes it assumes a zero matrix that is there in cell A1.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult yes.
My workaround was to show zero values in the sheet (ugly unfortunately)
And then do

```
=IF(targetcell=0, do nothing, do the thing I want)
```

Because my targetcell references a list on another sheet. If that list entry is blank, show a 0 and don't do the formula.

Hope helps, Alex

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the other day. I had to get rid of the "empty" rows (not blank, because they contained a formula) in a range. My solution was to colour them with Conditional Formatting (the rule was searching for ""), then filter the column for the coloured cells, then "Go to special" -> "Visible cells only", press "Delete" and then "Entire row" :-)
Cheers, Carolin